# How can I update sqlite3 after any time login in Django 2.2?

Tags: django, sqlite, authentication

I use   `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`  in Django for Authentication.
I want update 1 column of `auth_user` table  when any user login.

```
 @login_required 
 def showMag(request):
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [user_logged_in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) signal

```
def login_additional_function(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # user -> The user instance that just logged in.
    user.changefield = field
    user.save()

user_logged_in.connect(login_additional_function)
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i update  column ` x`  in table auth_user  ?  how can i print  auth_user   ?

Comment: what did you try after i provided you with signal, you can get user instance directly as per docs

Comment: I want when user with name `test` login   save number 2 in  column ` x` in table auth_user.

Comment: so you write your code in signal function as i described

Comment: i have error with your code. 'User' object has no attribute 'connect'. what is 
`user_logged_in `? i replace `request.user ` with 
`user_logged_in `

Comment: user_logged_in is signal, if you follow documentation link that I have attached to my answer you would see that signal sends you back logged in user in argument when user logs in. Your code should be inside login_additional_function i have already commented out where from you get user instance

Comment: More about signals 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/